# My visitor counter is called 2 times every page load

Tags: node.js, firebase, angular6

I'm setting up a page for 2 weeks, with angular 6 and nodejs firebase backend... and its been a ride for sure everything works properly.
But I searched for visitor counter code and found another article on here,
and in theory, it is supposed to work, however angular in universal and everything set up.

I don't know if its a favicon.ico call or what makes the call but every refresh updates the counter 2 times.
So I narrowed it down to either favicon call or app.component being loaded twice in universal>? is anybody good with this on here =)

Ok its surprisingly a lot of code but this is the angular 6

```
  hello() {
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      //.set('Authorization', 'my-auth-token')
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

this.http.get<alpha>('https://xxx.co:8000/visitors/',{headers:headers})
.subscribe(data => {this.totalvisits=parseInt(data.name)    });
```

}

the xxx is just placeholder, but this is just the call to the backend, in the backend
I add a visitor in firebase read firebase and return the value to data.name...
but apparently, it refreshes twice every time so app. component call backend two times... I was just curious if anyone had any idea..

Comment: Please edit your post with corresponding code.

Comment: Which code you have used?

Comment: What is your backend code for handling the request?